# When i am trying to add custom domain for my repository it says Domain is already Taken

Tags: github, github-pages, github-pages-deploy-action

I need a quick help here.

I have created the repository on GitHub that I need to publish as a website. When I am trying to connect it with a custom domain, it says the domain is already taken.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4Op8L.png)

I followed the steps mentioned in this support article and verified domain ownership by adding TXT Record and now it says the domain is verified.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SUxn3.png)

Still, when I am trying to add a custom domain for my repository I am getting the error messages stating `` The custom domain `mehtaabhishek.in` is already taken. If you are the owner of this domain, check out https://docs.github.com/pages/configuring-a-custom-domain-for-your-github-pages-site/verifying-your-custom-domain-for-github-pages for information about how to verify and release this domain. ``

Request your quick help here.

Regards,
Abhishek

Comment: At which point are you stuck here: https://docs.github.com/pages/configuring-a-custom-domain-for-your-github-pages-site/verifying-your-custom-domain-for-github-pages

Comment: Hey @MarkusMeyer if you see the 2nd image, that domain is already added and verified.